# Completely uninstalling both versions of Xcode

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, uninstallation

As usual I typed sudo Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

It uninstalled the first version (Beta) properly. 
Tried the same thing on the older Stable Version which I have installed to "Xcode Stable"

Getting this error
Use of uninitialized value $dir_name in substitution (s///) at Library/uninstall-devtools line 153.
Use of uninitialized value $developer_dir in concatenation (.) or string at Library/uninstall-devtools line 120

Anyone else facing this problem? Can I just trash the installation folder?

Comment: Ok, Just Trashed it and re-installed XCode 3.2 iOS 4 GM. Nothing happened... So I assume nothing will happen in future as well...

Answer (score 15):

I got that same error message this morning as well.

It doesn't seem to want to cooperate if run from the same folder it lives, `/Developer/Library/`; running it from another location, such as `/`, will allow the script to complete the uninstallation without further incident.

Comment: Though this answer is a few years old, it just fixed a problem I've basically had all day.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and remove all files/directories, to completely uninstall Xcode

> 1. /Applications/Xcode.app
> 2. /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
> 3. ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
> 4. ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.Playground.plist  //if you want to reset play ground
> 5. ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.xcodebuild.plist
> 6. ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
> 7. ~/Library/Application Support/Xcode
> 8. ~/Library/Developer/Xcode
> 9. ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator